# The object override the previous one for the object array

Tags: java, arrays, object

For the main function, I try to build some object `all_data[]` from 0 to 4, but when the statement `System.out.println(all_data[0].getName());` 
they will output the most updated one (apple,orange,water,coke,Banana) 
, not "apple".

```
public class food_data {
    public static int food_drink; //1=food,2=drink
    public static String name;
    public static food_data[] all_data = new food_data[1000];
    public food_data(int food_drink, String name) {
        this.food_drink=food_drink;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public int getFoodDrink()
    {
        return this.food_drink;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public static void main()
    {

        all_data[0]= new food_data(1,"apple");
        System.out.println(all_data[0].getName());
        all_data[1]= new food_data(1,"orange");
        System.out.println(all_data[0].getName());
        all_data[2]= new food_data(0,"water");
        System.out.println(all_data[0].getName());
        all_data[3]= new food_data(0,"coke");
        System.out.println(all_data[0].getName());
        all_data[4]= new food_data(1,"Banana");
        System.out.println(all_data[0].getName());
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In every System.out.println you call all_data[0], which of course prints out always the same object. Just increment the index here the same as you do for the assignments.

Edit: Ok, now i see the problem. You made all fields in the class food_data as static, which means, they are not object specific. Remove the static keyword, then the program should work correctly.

Comment: No, i mean result will output the latest object, not the same object

Comment: How about i want to called this class from another class without using static?

Comment: Just create a new object from that class. You can leave the all_data field as static to hold all values, but in principle the food_data should just be a value object with name and food_drink as fields and respective getters and setters. Here you mix a value object with other business logic (main method etc) which should be in separate classes. I strongly recommend you read a proper tutorial to get into Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

change your main method as

```
 public static void main()
{

    all_data[0]= new food_data(1,"apple");
    all_data[1]= new food_data(1,"orange");
    all_data[2]= new food_data(0,"water");
    all_data[3]= new food_data(0,"coke");
    all_data[4]= new food_data(1,"Banana");
 for(int i=0; i< all_data.length; i++)
      {
         if( null != all_data[i])
             {
               System.out.println(all_data[i].getName());
             }
       }
}
```

you need to put data in array `all_data` then create loop and iterate over array. print array's element at each index.

Comment: This will cause NullPointerExceptions, because all_data[].length is 1000, but you only populate the first five entries.

Comment: So if i have 10 foods,  i should set all_data be all_data[10] to prevent nullpointerexception?

Comment: @Dummy: you could also use an ArrayList. There you can just add new elements without thinking about the size.